# rails 4 strong params session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authentication

I am using a custom passwordless login for my app. A user simply needs to enter their username or email, and then a unique login link with a token is sent to them. They enter their username or email into a simple form :

```
<%= form_tag request_token_path, id:'login-form' do %>
     <%= text_field_tag :user_id %>
<% end %>
```

This posts to a `sessions#request_token` method which verifies whether that user exists and then sends along the login link.

```
def request_token
   lookup = session_params[:user_id]
   if lookup.include? '@'
     @user = User.find_by(email: lookup)
   else
     @user = User.cached_find(lookup)
   end
   if @user
     @user.send_login_link
     redirect_to login_path, notice: "#{@user.username.capitalize} your email was sent!"
   else
     redirect_to login_path, notice: "Whoops! Looks like #{lookup} is not registered on this site. Please check spelling or signup!"
   end
 end
```

My question is that in my `SessionsController` file I defined the `sessions_params`

```
private
def session_params
  params.require(:session).permit(:user_id,:auth_token)
end
```

I know that means that I have to use a session object or in order to pass along the `:user_id` from the form since I defined `:user_id` as a param that is on valid as an attribute of a session. I am wondering the correct way to do this. Making a new session object doesn't make sense since that isn't even a model I have but is it safe to just take it from the params?

and instead make `lookup = params[:user_id]` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a session object that responds to user_id attribute, you need to create the form for that object specifically:

```
<%= form_for @session do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :user_id %>
<% end %>
```

If that's not the case, and you need to stick to form_tag, try making the attribute name something that would come up in the controller as a session hash:

```
<%= text_field_tag "session[user_id]" %>
```

When you do

```
params.require(:session)
```

it means you're requiring your params hash to have a session key, which in turn should have the permitted user_id attribute:

```
{params: {session: {user_id: "something"}}
```

And thats why you'd need form_for @session OR the textfield with the suggested "session[user_id]" name

Comment: I understand why I need one or the other I'm just wondering which is safer to do. Making a session object seems safer since then I am using strong params but making a session object also doesn't make sense since it's just temporarily storing info and isn't an actual model.

Comment: It is a good practice to create session objects even if they are not a model. Creating objects and further a sessions resource would mean you can have a RESTful controller for your session, which is a good practice in Rails (create session, destroy session, etc)

Comment: But a `session` is already an object that exists with Rails, why would I create my own just to temporarily store information? My question is whether it is safe to send params that are not explicitly defined by the controller.